# Select anchor tag text within table which have multiple anchors

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I have a table and in each td I have assigned a href tag like, this

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: binddetails">
    <tr>                         
        <td><a class="info_link" data-bind="text: Status"></a></td>
        <td class="text-right"><a data-bind=" text: Count.toFixed(0)"></a></td>
        <td class="text-right"><a data-bind=" text: Total.toFixed(0)"></a></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

When i click the link I need to get the value of the particular td. I wrote the jQuery method to get the text but I get null value.

```
$(function () {
    $('.info_link').click(function () {
        alert($(this).text());
    });
});
```

Comment: It returns Null because .text() returns text between the <a> and </a> tags

Comment: Let's imagine that this `data-bind` attribute results in having _status_ text inside `<a>`. Then it does work: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vm0f76jk/).

Comment: @Riddler : I have bind the text in between the <a> tags. When I click it returns null

Comment: Pls post the rendered `HTML` and not the server side one.

Comment: @Crisim; how can I get the tag value by adding knockout..? can u explain?

Comment: That should work ideally. Use debugger to check `$(this)`

Comment: May be you are calling Knockout lately .. try adding knockout before all javascript calls.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this without jquery, like this:

```
function YourViewModel() {
    //binddetails...
    this.showStatus = function (details) {
        alert(details.Status());
    }
};
```

HTML:

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: binddetails">
    <tr>                         
        <td><a class="info_link" data-bind="text: Status, click: $root.showStatus"></a></td>
        <td class="text-right"><a data-bind=" text: Count.toFixed(0)"></a></td>
        <td class="text-right"><a data-bind=" text: Total.toFixed(0)"></a></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get the text that is inside each td (as you say in your question ) you can write:

```
$('td').click(function () {
    alert($(this).text());
});
```

if you want to get the text that is inside each a tag (that is what your code is trying to do) you can write:

```
$('td>a').click(function () {
    alert($(this).text());
});
```

Anyway you have nothing inside the td or a to be displayed so nothing can be alerted.
If your code is like this you will get a value:

```
<td>dummy<a class="info_link" data-bind="text: Status"></a></td>
```

will return a value only in the first option (return the td value).
If your html is like this you will get a value with both code:

```
<td><a class="info_link" data-bind="text: Status">Dummy.</a></td>
```

In both cases you will get "Dummy" as alerted value.

Comment: <td><a class="info_link" data-bind="text: Status">Active</a></td>  --- This is the rendered html i'm getting. Hope there is value between the <a> tag but still it returns the null value

Comment: @AarthiRavendiran I have already provided fiddle in question's comments which shows that orignal code does work.

Comment: @Regent Yeah u showed the output in JSFiddle. That is what I expected.. But i'm not getting it in my screen even when I implemented it as such..